# Computer names on a network, my.computer.name

Tags: vb.net

The way we get my.computer.name, can we also get the name of all computers on a network?

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting 'my.computer.name'?

Comment: @IAbstract 'My' is a namespace in Vb.net Computer is a property in this Namespace which exposes access on computer properties like the Name etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do this by installing a DNS server and mapping the network from another program.

Windows has a nice built in network map, and you can also use something like NMap (Zenmap) to do it.